verifyPhoneNumber in Flutter/Firebase app not working ('token mismatch')
I've been trying to get 'signinwithphonenumber' working for DAYS now, but I just can't seem to do it on iOS. It works fine on Android, but try as I might, I cannot get the iOS version to work.
This is how I sign-in to firebase:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: '<app name>',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).then((_) {
    print("Firebase initialized successfully.");
  }).catchError((error) {
    print("Error initializing Firebase: $error");
  });

// Clear Firestore persistence here
  try {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    print('Firestore persistence cleared.');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error clearing Firestore persistence: $e');
  }

  // Set Firestore settings
  try {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = const Settings(
      persistenceEnabled: false,
      sslEnabled: false,
      cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
    );
    print('Firestore settings updated.');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error setting up Firestore: $e');
  }

  globals.fbdb = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  globals.fbauth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  globals.fbs = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  // Run the app
  runApp(const <appname>());
}

This is where I try to verify the phone number:
  static Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

    print("+++ phoneNumber = ${phoneNumber}");
    await globals.fbauth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        // Auto-retrieve verification code
        print("Verification Complete has been triggered for some reason!");
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        // Verification failed
        print('+++ Verification failed. Error = ${e}');
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        // Save the verification ID for future use
        print('got through to codeSent section');
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
    );
  }
}

And this always triggers the 'verificationFailed' section, with the error 'Token mismatch'.
This is the AppDelegate.swift:
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseAuth

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Firebase initialization
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            print(userInfo)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    }
}

Flutter version = 3.24.3 <> Stable channel
Dart 3.5.3
Devtools 2.37.3
Xcode: Version 15.4 (15F31d)
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
Mac mini M2 Pro - 32GB
Testing on an iPhone 13 (real device)

There are no compile issues
All the plugins are up to date (all the Firebase ones are the latest versions available)
The 'firebase-options.dart' file is set up and correct (checked)
The URL Type with the REVERSE_CLIENT_ID is correct
I've checked and double checked all the certificates from Apple, and the .p8 key has been re-generated about 4 times now just to ensure I wasn't having some kind of blackout (!) when I was generating it or something
'Authentication' on the Firebase console is set up with 'Sign in with Google', 'Sign In with phone number' and 'sign in with email address and password' - all of which are enabled.
The bundle names are all correct, as is the name of the Firebase app everywhere it's referenced
I've switched the 'Autogenerated Key for iOS' in Google Cloud Platform to being locked to iOS applications
I'm a paid Apple Developer
The right provisioning profile is set up
The GoogleService-Info.plist is in the right place and all the content is correct
The Background modes in the 'signing & capabilities' section are set to 'Background Fetch' and 'Remote Notifications'

This is from hours upon hours of scouring StackOverflow, reading and re-reading the documentation from Google, and doing everything I can think of to get this to work...
...but all the same code (exactly) works perfectly on Android.
HELP! I'm losing the will to live!

Finally, I found the solution after a week of searching:

Locate the file firebase_sdk_version.rb and modify the version to 11.2.0.
Image of the file location

Run:
pod update FirebaseAuth Firebase

Then:
pod install


After that, run your app, and everything should work!

Actually, simply update your Firebase pub dependencies to latest, which should pull on firebase_ios_sdk 11.2.0. But you're right, the fix is here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/13539 which was release in 11.2.0
